# Installing Foundation-Icon-Fonts via Bower in --libsass environment

Tags: gruntjs, zurb-foundation, bower, libsass, foundation-icon-fonts

I'm using Foundation 5 - foundation-libsass-template. Using bower I've added foundation-icons with the following command `"bower install foundation-icons --save"`. This command downloads the foundation-icon package and saves it to the bower_components folder and modifies my `bower.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "foundation-libsass-template",
  "dependencies": {
    "foundation": "zurb/bower-foundation",
    "foundation-icon-fonts": "zurb/foundation-icon-fonts"
  }
}
```

Problem: 
When I add `@import "foundation-icon-fonts";` to my app.scss file Grunt returns an error because it can't find the file:

> Warning:
>   C:/Users/Chris/Websites/example.com/lp/new/scss/app.scss:3:
>   file to import not found or unreadable: "foundation-icon-fonts"

Question 1: 
Do I need to modify the Grunt.js file in order to include this library? If so, could someone please provide an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't use that package, but the `@import` CSS directive (and the Sass version) requires a correct path for the import. So, since you're using this as a Bower module, I'd imagine you would need something like:

```css
@import "bower_components/foundation-icons/path-to-styles.css";
```

Looking at the Bower package when I install it on my system, however, it looks like there are multiple directories in there with fonts and stylesheets:

```
.bower.json
foundation_icons_accessibility/
foundation_icons_general/
foundation_icons_general_enclosed/
foundation_icons_social/
.gitignore
MIT-LICENSE.txt
README.markdown
```

So you might have to specify the directory?

```css
@import "bower_components/path-to-foundation/foundation_icons_general/sass/general_foundicons.css";
```